# Django html button is not opening web browser with selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium, webautomation

I want a button on my django project home page that when clicked runs a .py file and opens a new browser using selenium. Following is my code but it is not working -

html -

```
<form action="/simple_function">
  <button id="stat-btn" class="btn">Generate Challan1</button>
</form>
```

views -

```
# import function to run
from .generate import Generate

def simple_function(request):
    GenerateChallan()
```

Urls.py -

```
path("simple_function", views.simple_function),
```

Python script in generate.py -

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


class Generate():
    def GenerateChallan():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get('https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp')
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1012)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.execute_script('javascript:sendRequest(281)')
```

Now its working!

Comment: `GenerateChallan()` is a method. You need to create a `Generate` object to call it. But I think, you don't need it to be inside the `Generate` class. Just make it a simple function, import it and call it.

Comment: I have removed the class but I don't know how to create a generate object to call. Can you explain that further?

Comment: Why do you need to create a `Generate` object? Just call your `GenerateChallan` (like you literally call it in your code)

Comment: I have now called it directly in my views.(refer code above) but still not working.  please give some more direction where i'm going wrong

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. You don't import the function. The function doesn't have any arguments and you are trying to pass some number. Also, we can't really know what "not working" means.

Comment: Got it. finally understood how to run the function directly. have posted the code above. Thank a lot